# bootsrap4 datatable pagination div show inside the table. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have converted bootstarp3 datatable into bootstrap4. Pagination div show in datatable but I want this outside. I want solution for this problem. Thank u so much for advance.

Comment: Please include a working example of the problem within your solution.

Comment: [look here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/51067/bootstrap-4-styling-not-working)